# How to use RegEx in JavaScript replace function

Tags: javascript

Hello team I am new to JS so I am trying to use RegEx with replacing to take input from the user and replace it if it doesn't match the RegEx I have to be able to put 7 digits or 6 digits followed with one letter currently I am doing this

> `someID.replace('^(([0-9]{1,7})|([0-9]{1,6}[a-zA-Z]{1}))$')`

I am not able to replace the current string with the RegEx expression if I enter
12345678900 it remain the same in that situation I need to be 1234567 after the replace or if I have 12345678asd to be 123456a. How can I achieve that by only replace function and a RegEx expresion

Comment: OK, but what's your question? What problem are you facing? Please read [ask] and edit your question to include more details and elaborate on the problem.

Comment: You need to wrap the regex in backslash `/` not `'` to create a regex literal: `replace(/^(([0-9]{1,7}.....$/ , '')`

Comment: There is the second argument for replace() missing to tell what should be put in. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp ...

Comment: And finally, `replace` doesn't do the job in place, it returns a new string.

Comment: You have to omit the semicolons arround the regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different regex and a dirrent `replace` function.
You will also need to get rid of `$` if you want to be able to successfully match the string, without worrying about how it ends.

```js
const sampleIDs = [
  "123456789000",
  "123456abc",
  ];
  
sampleIDs.forEach(id => {
  const clean = id.match(/^\d{6}[\d\D]/);
  console.log(clean[0]);
});
```